# how can i get retrofit response from local ip

Tags: api, retrofit2

i am using esp8266 as localhost with 192.168.4.1 address and i want to request get by my app. i'm using retrofit library. esp8266 coding is true and tested by Chrome.

public static final String LOCAL_API_BASE_URL = "http://192.168.4.1/";

and in service class:
    @GET("deka")
    Call hello();

Comment: your LOCAL_API_BASE_URL  is invalid.

Comment: sushildlh please write your answer with  reason and guide me to make it valid. Thanks